# Can I distribute a commercial software with R packaged (and a couple of libraries)li

Tags: r, rjava

A software I am developing uses rJava to call for R scripts (that I programmed). These R scripts use different libraries from R.

Say I want to sell this software, and, to ease the installation process, include R packaged in the distribution (with it's source code). My application could then simply use this packaged version of R to execute, without having the user fiddle with environment variable, or having to install R at all.

I am not sure how "viral" the GNU GPL license of R and its libraries are, and when I looked up on google, I had mixed feelings about it.

So, can I package R and some libraries with my commercial software ?

Comment: Also I am not sure if this question should be on stackoverflow or opensource.exchange, so please let me know if it's the wrong place to ask such question.

Comment: SO is not the place for license questions. There are a couple of posts on Meta regarding this, that may be worth reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Open Source Initiative](https://opensource.org/docs/definition.html);

> The license shall not restrict any party from selling or giving away
>   the software as a component of an aggregate software distribution
>   containing programs from several different sources. The license shall
>   not require a royalty or other fee for such sale.

Looks like what you want to do is ok.

As an aside, while I was answering this question I was installing [Alteryx](http://www.alteryx.com/) which is commercial software that comes packaged with R.

Comment: Ok, but I have to link to some rJava (JRI) API in order to be able to call R scripts in my GUI. Does that mean that my software has to be GPL / LGPL too ? And thus that I'll have to provide the source code ?

Comment: Can you please follow up on this? I am in the exact same situation. Thanks.